# How can I calculate the probability of a red King or Queen in R?

Tags: r

This is the rds file I've been working with named Deck_of_Cards: https://easyupload.io/u4zbem. If I want to calculate P((Queen ∪ King) ∩ Red) how can I add in the latter part, Red, in a code?

When I calculated the P(Queen u King) it worked fine:

```
    Probability_of_a_Red_Queen_or_King <- nrow(subset(Deck_of_Cards, card == "Queen" | card == "King",)) / nrow(Deck_of_Cards)
```

But trying to add in the color Red it didn't run:

```
    Probability_of_a_Red_Queen_or_King <- nrow(subset(Deck_of_Cards, card == "Queen" | card == "King",) & color == "Red",)) / nrow(Deck_of_Cards)
```

How could I go about this?

Comment: Try `subset(Deck_of_Cards, (card == "Queen" | card == "King") & color == "Red",)`.

Comment: You just had some typos: `Probability_of_a_Red_Queen_or_King <- nrow(subset(Deck_of_Cards, (card == "Queen" | card == "King") & color == "Red")) / nrow(Deck_of_Cards)`. No commas after King and Red and enclose card == "Queen" | card == "King" in parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
`subset(Deck_of_Cards, color == 'Red', card == "Queen" | card == "King")`